# My getcomponent<class> is not returning an array that exist in the other script

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have two different scripts with one class each:

```
public string[] sferagenerataspecifica = new string[35];
public string[] sferageneratarandom = new string[35];
...
public string[] GenerasferaSpecifica(string nome = "testname", string livello = "One")
{
    sferagenerataspecifica[0] = nome;
    sferagenerataspecifica[1] = livello;
    return sferagenerataspecifica;
}
```

I checked and it returns both values.
The other script is:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "OggettoSferaIniziale")
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("nomeSfera1", sferagenerataspecifica[0]);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("livelloSfera1", sferagenerataspecifica[1]);
    }
}
```

I keep receiving the error

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

and nothing is being saved to playerprefs.

What am I missing?

Why is getcomponent not retrieving the contents of the array sferagenerataspecifica and why is the array suddenly null?

Comment: Hi, are the scripts assigned to the same object? Sorry but I cannot understand this for sure. (I think not, because there's a collision. Can you try with `collision.gameObject.GetComponent<ScacchieraIntro>().sferagenerataspecifica[0]` ?)

Comment: Oh, snap I just realized I attached one of the scripts in a different scene. Now I merged them into one and it's not giving me errors. But when I test the collision instead of printing the actual strings it's printing "System.object".

Comment: Can you please update with the actual code? Because there are no prints right now!

Comment: I feel so stupid, I didn't call the method that fills the array so it was constantly empty. It's now working as intended. I'm sorry if the explanation was confusing. Thanks for your first comment andrea!

Comment: Great :) Fell free to answer your own post and accept it. Good luck with your project!